# Передача в функцию значения ячейки StringGrid

Tags: c++builder, c++

Проблема вот в чем. Мне нужно передать в созданую мной функцию значение ячейки стандартного объекта `StringGrid`. Я создал свой класс и функцию. Как сделать чтобы значение ячейки `StringGrid` можно было передать в мою функцию? Вот кусок кода:

```
class Parsing     
{    
public:  
        int k;  
         void TPar(String str);  
         int GetValue(String str);  
};  
int Parsing::GetValue(String str)  
{  
    int Pos;     
    Pos=StringGrid1->Cells[1][1];      
}
```

Comment: При копилировании выдает ошибку: Undefined symbol "StringGrid1"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вариант 1) в конструкторе класса Parsing сделать параметр, куда передавать нужный StringGrid

```
class Parsing     
{    
    private:
        TStringGrid * StringGrid;
    public: 
    //...
        Parsing(TStringGrid* st):StringGrid(st) {}
    int Parsing::GetValue(String str)  
    {  
        int Pos;     
        Pos=StringGrid->Cells[1][1];      
    }
```

И в коде можно будет ссылаться на StringGrid. В коде пишем так

```
Parsing p(StringGrid1);
p.GetValue("str");
```

Вариант 2) сделать Form1 глобальной переменной и тогда в классе можно будет писать Form1->StringGrid1->Cells[1][1], но это не очень правильный вариант.